# React Function undefined at onClick although it's bound?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-redux

I have this function:

```
  deleteTag() {
    // this.data.tags.pop();
    console.log("I will delete a tag");
  }
```

I bind it in the constructor:

```
this.deleteTag = this.deleteTag.bind(this);
```

But when I try to do this:

```
render() {
    const renderTags = this.state.data.tags.map(function(tag,i){
      return <span key={i} onClick={() => this.deleteTag()}>{tag} </span>
    });

   return ( <div> {renderTags} </div> );
}
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteTag' of undefined
>       at onClick (bundle.js:46275)
>       at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:4594)
>       at executeDispatch (bundle.js:4394)
>       at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (bundle.js:4417)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (bundle.js:3847)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (bundle.js:3858)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at forEachAccumulated (bundle.js:4694)
>       at Object.processEventQueue (bundle.js:4063)
>       at runEventQueueInBatch (bundle.js:4723)

I'm sure it's something silly, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's becuase the function given to `map` is not bound. You could use an arrow function instead, and `this` will be what you expect.

```
const renderTags = this.state.data.tags.map((tag,i) => {
  return <span key={i} onClick={() => this.deleteTag()}>{tag} </span>
});
```

Comment: omg so silly of me! thanks a lot!!! (I gotta wait 12 minutes before picking the answer)